# How can I have an AngularJS module routes use its own controllers?

Tags: dependency-injection, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS' view and routing mechanism, following [AngularJS' own tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

My problem is the tutorial is declaring all its controllers in the global scope, and I belive this is a bad practice because we're polluting it as we add more controllers.

This is a quick working page I've been able to build following the aforementioned tutorial (there's [a fiddle, too](http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/7TGRY/)):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            "use strict";

            var MyFirstController = function ($scope) {
                // Do something here.
            };

            var MySecondController = function ($scope) {
                // Do something here.
            };

            var myModule = angular.module("MyModule", []);

            myModule.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when("/first-page", {
                    template: "<p>My first controller.</p>",
                    controller: MyFirstController
                });

                $routeProvider.when("/second-page", {
                    template: "<p>My second controller.</p>",
                    controller: MySecondController
                });
            }]);

            $(document).ready(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ["MyModule"]);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div data-ng-view></div>
        <p><a href="#/first-page">Click me!</a></p>
        <p><a href="#/second-page">Click me too!</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Being naïve, I tried to move the controllers inside the module:

```js
myModule.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/first-page", {
        template: "<p>My first controller.</p>",
        controller: MyFirstController
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/second-page", {
        template: "<p>My second controller.</p>",
        controller: MySecondController
    });
}]);

myModule.controller("MyFirstController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    // Do something here.
}]);

myModule.controller("MySecondController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    // Do something here.
}]);
```

Alas, it doesn't (obviously) work, throwing a `ReferenceError: MyFirstController is not defined` exception.

How can I have an AngularJS module use its own controllers in its own routes configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you know the solution, it's really simple: just specify the controller as strings instead of objects:

```js
myModule.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/first-page", {
        template: "<p>My first controller.</p>",
        controller: "MyFirstController"
    });

    $routeProvider.when("/second-page", {
        template: "<p>My second controller.</p>",
        controller: "MySecondController"
    });
}]);
```

This way AngularJS will resolve the controller name to the one you've defined inside the module.

And it's minification safe too!

I've created [a fiddle demonstrating it](http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/96hPJ/).